# how to automatically numbering the hyperlink reference list?

Tags: markdown, pandoc

```
# content
someone said[1][link text]
others said[2][another link]
but the fact is in between[3][yet another link]

# refs

1. [https://example1.com][link test]
2. [https://example2.com][another link]
3. [https://example3.com][yet another link]

[link text]: https://example1.com
[another link]: https://example2.com
[yet another link]: https://example3.com
```

1st I would like to avoid to write the number, because when there is a lot, I easily lost the track.

2nd I want to avoid write the #ref part myself at all. Can pandoc automatically generate a ref list numbered and show the actual link url or label text?